# NSXML Parser in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I need to get the value of the following xml , I am using NSXML parser for parsing this

```
<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>
```

I need to get the "true " value from the above xml .

What should I do inside the NSXML parser delegate methods?

Comment: please do some search before asking a question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation XMLParser

- (NSString *)parseXMLFile: (NSURL *) url
{   
    outstring = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];

        [parser setDelegate: self];
    [parser parse];
        [parser release];

    return [outstring autorelease];
}

//<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
                                              namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
                          qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
                          attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict   
{
        if (qName) elementName = qName;
    if (elementName) current = [NSString stringWithString:elementName];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
                         namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
                         qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    current = nil;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (!current) return;
    if ([current isEqualToString:@"boolean"]) 
        [outstring appendFormat:@"%@\n", string];
}

//  <boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>


-(void) parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"parserDidStartDocument");   
}

-(void) parserDidEndDocument: (NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"parserDidEndDocument %@", outstring);   
}
@end
```

[For more detail regarding the nsxml parse Reference site here.](http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C490/html/nsxmlparser.htm)

this may more help to you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want true value then do following:

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
    {
        strVal=string;
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    {
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"boolean"])
       {
          //you can get 'true' value here
       }

    }
```